# Finding the inverse of a $4×4$ matrix containing only letter values.

Tags: linear-algebra

The question: Find the inverse (if it exists) of the following $4 × 4$ matrix $M$:$$
\begin{bmatrix}
a & -b & -c & -d\\
 b & a & -d & c\\
c & d & a & -b\\
d & -c & b & a\\
\end{bmatrix}$$
In attempting to answer this question, I have receieved a tip from my professor to use the transformation of $M$ in order to find the inverse. Multiplying that, the matrix falls into another $4 × 4$ matrix with a form of the identity matrix but modified with polynomials (of course, since it's only letter values.) I'm wondering how to carry forward with this? I tried zero-ing out rows and columns in order to use cofactor expansion but I'm not finding myself getting anywhere. I appreciate any help.

Comment: Please use MathJax to format.

Comment: I  have no idea how to, but I'll look into it.

Comment: Thank you for helping me out with that.

Comment: Are you sure the 3rd row isn't $c,d,a,-b$?

Comment: Edited. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: @DF Your comment is irrelevant to the question

Answer (score 1):

can you complete the following equation?
$$
MM^T= ?
$$

Comment: I apologize for this not being the proper format but this is what I got. It'll be easier to just write it. The result is a 4x4 identity matrix but is modified so that each 1 is replaced with (A^2 + B^2 + C^2 + D^2.) I'm sure its used within the solution because of how well that dot product fits perfectly with the identity matrix but I'm not sure where to go from there.

Comment: @SEALK9 So $MM^T=(a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2)I$, how much is $M\cdot \frac{1}{a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2}M^T$?

Comment: OP - if you right-click on a math expression (for example in @user8734617's hint above) the drop-down menu allows you to click "Show Math As" then choose "Tex Commands". this is a quick and easy way of learning the basic MathJax syntax you will need on math.stackexchange.